# Codeigniter - Show 404 Page when User Types index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to show 404 page when user types index.php within the URL as:

```
http://localhost:8080/site_name/index.php/home
```

I add this in routes.php `$route['index.php/(:any)'] = 'custom404';`

It didn't help; when user types `http://localhost:8080/site_name/index.php/home` home page shows up instead of 404 not found.

**Any idea how to show 404 page when user types index.php within the URL?**

**My htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site_name/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Do you want all links go to custom404?

Comment: Only when index.php is present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the index.php from your urls all together.  It is on by default with CodeIgniter but you can remove it easily, just follow the guide here at their user guide:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

EDIT: it should also be known that the index.php in the url is not part of your controller, it is simply something put there by CodeIgniter so you cannot remove it by using your routes.

Comment: I could remove it using htacces, but i dont want it to be active. In other words, when user types it manually, he should get 404 page

Comment: yes, follow the instructions there to modify the htaccess file and then in your config.php file alter the line that says $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';  Change 'index.php' to have nothing in the quotes as directed in the comments above that line.

Answer (score 0):

set default controller to custom404

```
$route['default_controller'] = "custom404";
```

or you could try this:

```
$route['index.php/^(.+)$'] = "custom404";
```

Comment: Woud'nt even the normal URLs be routed to 404 page if default controller is set to custom404?

Comment: He can override them later if he want. But I guess he just want to set some maintance mode or something.

Comment: Well I am not sure what he wanted. I thought he didnt wanted the users to be explicitlly access index.php.

Comment: Maybe he could try some regex instead of (:any)

Comment: Yeah,  whenever user types index.php within url he  should be redirected to 404. I will test your second solution later